# How do I make a circular hole inside an editable poly without boolean operations?

Tags: 3dsmax

I have created a rectangle, then converted it into an editable poly. Then I created a circle and converted it to editable poly too. How to make it so that that the circle becomes a hole in the rectangle?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a **Boolean operation**. You can find a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwp2c-mAzkU) here for almost the exact situation you're asking about.

Essentially, it looks like you create a new object with your two objects selected. You'll likely need to make your circle a cylinder first. The new object is a Compound Object of type Boolean. Then in the operations you select A-B (where A is your rectangle and B is your cylinder).

It's still a boolean operation. It's just done with splines that share a common plane. Check the Boolean heading on this [page](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/files/GUID-EC9BB02A-FDE3-4B50-824E-07BE9E5ACE3C.htm).

Comment: Sorry that's correct but I would like to do this without boolean operations to learn how to use edge/vertex manipulation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. You seem to already know *how* you want to do it. What's there to answer?

Comment: I don't know how to combine primitive elements (like vertexes, edges etc) into whole, but I believed it is possible. Was I wrong?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Combining them "into whole" sounds less like "make a hole through the rectangle" and more like "make the rectangle have cylindrical pegs poking out its sides." If you're asking how to make a hole, you don't need to go about it in a less than straightforward way - unless you're trying to do something else! Is there something else?

Comment: I need to learn how to work with poly elements. This is an example I stucked at. How to make one outline to be an object and another one -- a hole in first?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use booleans...

1. Use INSET on the front and rear facing face. This creates a square polygon in the middle with edges going towards the corners of the cube.
2. Delete the new square polygons on each face.
3. Bridge the new gap created.

Obviously this creates a square hole. However, if you add more verts around the edges of the cube before using INSET, you could later manually shape the hole.

Comment: Sorry, this is for a cube... not rectangle. However, the same still applies minus the bridging part.

Answer (score 1):

I know, the question was asked about 3 years ago, but never mind.
I don't think the boolean operation is a good solution ant it is not required here. It is desined for other cases, to my mind.

So, you created 2 splines. You should convert one of them, for instance rectangle, to editable spline, than **Attach** the second. Than apply **Extrude** modifier. The nested object automatically becomes a hole in the parent object.

So the recipe is:

1. Create as many nested splies as you want, *wihout intersection*
2. Convert one of the to editable splie and **Attach** them all together
3. Use **Extrude** modifier

[image: Flat smile]
[image]

Therefore extruding a circle inside a circle (in other words a flat a ring) creates a tube.

The cap created automatically will be without any edges in it. If you are bothering about topology - you may:

- Cut it using **Cut** tool
- **Connect** vertices
- Remove cap and use **Bridge**
- Use **Quadify Mesh** modifier (doesn't give clean topology)

If you're creating game assets - that **Quadify Mesh** may be not desirable. But if you're going only to have smoothed model for one render - it's a quick way.

Your question seem to be more general than creating a cirular hole in a box but...

In case you want to create a perfectly round circle in a square (you may want to insert it into other objects) using *TurboSmooth*, you do

1. Create a plane 2*2
2. Create diagonal lines (connect or cut)
3. Chamfer the vertext in the middle
4. Delete polygone in the center

Here we are, having low poly model.

[image: 2*2 plane]
[image: Hole in the plane]

And that is is. Other steps are necessary only for smoothing:

5. Prepare edges for smoothing (add some density near the corners)
6. Apply **TurboSmooth**

[image: Some additional edges]
[image: TurboSmooth]

Answer (score 0):

this video shows how to create a circle in your square using the 'loop tools' in the graphite editor. Works perfect, maintains quads everywhere. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwzqn3K7RxE

Comment: Link-only answers are unreliable; they tend to rot over time.  It would be better to offer some summary of the steps involved in the text of your answer.